# Codemagic issue with provisioning profile

Tags: ios, flutter, provisioning-profile, codemagic

When building iOS project on Codemagic I get the following error:

```
Completed configuring code signing settings
    Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
    Generated options for exporting the project
     - Method: ad-hoc
     - Provisioning Profiles: []
     - Signing Certificate: 
     - Signing Style: manual
     - Team Id:

Encountered error while building IPA:
error: Couldn't load -exportOptionsPlist: Failed to decode "provisioningProfiles". Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.
```

Any solution?

[codemagic.yaml](https://pastebin.com/DZtw0CeR)

Comment: hey, can you update your question with fragment `codemagic.yaml` file or relevant Workflow Editor settings?

Comment: I'm using the workflow editor, but have the same issue despite having uploaded the certificate and provisioning profile. Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

`release-pipeline` workflow you shared doesn't have the following mandatory steps to publish to App Store:

- code signing configuration
- building `.ipa`

Looks like it was configured for Google Play only.

Check this example https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-quick-start/building-a-flutter-app/#ios-builds

Comment: Can you be maybe more specific, what exactly part of the setup for iOS is not valid? @MikhailTokarev

Comment: hey @Joe I've updated my answer, hope you will find a time to check the example by the link I shared